# Drupal Migrate - Class No Longer Exists

Tags: migrations

I hope that someone can help me, because I am now becoming desperate. I've stared at this for hours and cannot figure out what is going wrong.

I am trying to set up a very simple migration following to the letter the example in Drupalize Me of baseball players.

I have built all the relevant files and checked the code.

I clear the cache with drush and then register the static migrations. It tells me that they are registered.

I then do a migration status call and it reports that the "Class XXXX no longer exists"

I cannot find my error and it's driving me mad.

Has anyone run into this, or can anyone recommend any pitfalls that I should consider please?

Chris